# How can I send a web request from a Chrome extension without running into the issue of CORS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do not want to use a CORS proxy.

I tried to search it on the internet but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @phuzi I get a CORS error with that solution

Comment: Show us your code and manifest etc.

Comment: I use a content script to run some js, can that be the problem?

Comment: Possibly, you haven't shown us any code so I'm unable to comment!

Comment: This is the js:
```js
    fetch("https://somewebsite/somethingelse")
        .then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```
This is a part of the manifest:
```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "somescript.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://somewebsite/*"
  ]```
edit: its easier to see here https://hastebin.com/share/oqijijideb.css

Comment: Can you put the relevant code and the manifest in the question please?